# JavaScript how do we apply moment js date format to a whole array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angular, momentjs

I have an array with 15 dates.
I want to be able to loop through array and apply `[moment js][1]` date format function.
The function below only logs first date where as array has two dates *date0* and *date1*.

```
var FormatDate = moment (DateArray).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(FormatDate);
```

[image]

Comment: `arr.map(function(d) { return moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to loop through dateArray. You can use destructuring assignment to get each keys value, and build / return the object with the moment format

```js
let dateArray = [
  {date0: 1577105280760, date1: 1577291680760},
  {date0: 1577391680760, date1: 1577478080760},
  {date0: 1575278080760, date1: 1576364480760},
  {date0: 1577364480760, date1: 1578450880760},
  {date0: 1597450880760, date1: 1587537280760},
];

// Answer
let momentDates = dateArray.map(({date0, date1}) => {
  return {
    date0: moment(date0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    date1: moment(date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  };
});

console.log(momentDates);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.prototype.map()` operator:

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

Example usage of map operator:

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// pass a function to map

const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);

console.log(map1);
// expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]
```

In your case:

```js
let newArray = dateArray.map(({date0, date1}) => {
  return {
    date0: moment(date0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    date1: moment(date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  };
});
```

For further reference, please find the link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

Use **`map`** method of an **`array`**. Iterate over **`DateArray`** and convert **`date0`** and **`date1`** using **`moment`** and then **`return`** item;

```
   this.modifiedDateArray = DateArray.map(item => { 
        item.date0 = moment(item.date0).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        item.date1 = moment(item.date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        return item;
     })

   console.log(modifiedDateArray);
```

Comment: @sam Assign it to new array and check the console.

Answer (score 0):

This one maps both properties of your object `date0`  and `date1`. And this one doesn't change the original object

```js
DateArray.map(
  elem => {
    return {    
      date0: moment(elem.date0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), 
      date1: moment(elem.date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    };
  }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code.

```
array.forEach((data)=>{
return moment(data).formate('YYYY-MM-DD');
})
```